# accessing python 2D array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

suppose we have:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

What is the fastest way to access the array such that we get the first element in each list, other than looping.

i would like the result to be giving me... 1,4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using zip(*a)

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
result = zip(*a)[0]
print result
```

Comment: As a side note, this doesn't work in python3 as `zip` returns an iterable object... `next(iter(zip(*a)))` should work just about anywhere though.

Comment: `list(zip(*a))[0]` works in python2.7, and IMHO will also work in python3.0, because `list()` accepts an iterable and produces a list.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy way is to just extract `a[0][0]` and `a[1][0]`, but depending on what you are using it for, this might not work all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Without looping, you need to unroll the loop as ethg242 does. This has the disadvantage of only working for a fixed length of `a`

Here is a list comprehension

```
[i[0] for i in a]
```

It's also possible to use `map()`, but this also has an implicit loop

```
from operator import itemgetter
map(itemgetter(0), a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = np.array(a)
>>> b[:,0]
array([1, 4])
```

Comment: thanks you, but how do you convert this 2d array to a 1d array? I'm looking for a quick function haha :) much appreciated!

Comment: array([1,4]) is equivalent to [[1],[4]]